# How to split and remove unwanted string in url?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('log1.txt', 'w')

url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/tamil-font-513607.html'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in soup.select("div.class1.coLeft a[href]"):
    try:
        suburl = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
        f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
    except:
        print 'cannot read'
        f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

        pass

    content = urllib.urlopen(suburl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.select("div.Sever1.coLeft a[href]"):
        try:
            suburl2 = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
            f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

            pass

        content = urllib.urlopen(suburl2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
        try:
            suburl3 = soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]
            print suburl3.replace("&" + url.split('&')[-1],"")
            #f.write (soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write(soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]+'\n')

            pass
f.close()
```

I want the output should be like this:

http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=159403&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fmp3_audio%2Fmidi_tools%2FSynthFontSetup.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = "http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=159403&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fmp3_audio%2Fmidi_tools%2FSynthFontSetup.exe&name=SynthFont"
print url.replace("&" + url.split('&')[-1],"")
```

Output:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=159403&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fmp3_audio%2Fmidi_tools%2FSynthFontSetup.exe
```

---

Your code (with changes):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('log1.txt', 'w')

url ='http://www.brothersoft.com/tamil-font-513607.html'
pageUrl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageUrl)

for a in soup.select("div.class1.coLeft a[href]"):
    try:
        suburl = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
        f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
    except:
        print 'cannot read'
        f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

        pass

    content = urllib.urlopen(suburl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.select("div.Sever1.coLeft a[href]"):
        try:
            suburl2 = ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']).encode('utf-8','replace')
            f.write ('http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write('cannot read:'+'http://www.brothersoft.com'+a['href']+'\n')

            pass

        content = urllib.urlopen(suburl2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
        try:
            suburl3 = soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]
            print suburl3
            print suburl3.replace("&" + suburl3.split('&')[-1],"")
            #f.write (soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]+'\n')
        except:
            print 'cannot read'
            f.write(soup.find('body')['onload'][10:-2]+'\n')

            pass
f.close()
```

Output:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.brothersoft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusfiles.brothersoft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe&name=Tamil%20Font
http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=513607&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusfiles.brothersoft.com%2Fphotograph_graphics%2Ffont_tools%2Fkeyman.exe
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I edited my question..I tried your code but it did not change.

Comment: Your code output completely different URL string from your desirable output. Change it, so I could see what you need

Comment: Yes,thats what I want. Where did u change it? I cant see it.

Comment: You have to change `url` to `suburl3` twice (before and after replace)

Comment: You mean in the last try:?

Comment: yes, if in future you will need to find difference in code, you can use tools such as `diff`

Comment: oh man,I just found it..I dont know why I cant see it earlier.